# How to call a C# method using ajax in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I have a meeting table data and i am using it to send to server side page check my url and tell me why call is not sucessfull even data is passed correctly
here is my ajax call

```
    $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             url: 'AddNewMeeting.aspx/SaveMeetingShechudar',
             dataType: 'json',
             data: JSON.stringify(Meeting),
             success: function (response) {
                 alert("success ");
             },
             error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)   //what to do if fails
             {
                 //  alert('bad, ' + errorThrown + ", " + jqXHR.responseText + ", " + textStatus);
                 alert("success failed ");

             },
         });
```

here is my code of AddNewMeeting.aspx file

```
  public static void SaveMeetingShechudar(string MDate, string MTime, int MPurpose, int masterID, int RowNumber, string[] name, string[] nic, string[] designation, string[] company, string[] address)
    {
        int mID = 0;
        try
        {

            #region master part save
            MeetingSchedulMaster master = new MeetingSchedulMaster();
            master.m_date = Convert.ToDateTime(MDate);
            master.m_datetime = MTime;
            master.m_host = UserID;
            master.m_puposeid = Convert.ToInt32(MPurpose);
            master.m_entry_date = DateTime.Now;

            if (masterID == 0)
                saveDataMaster(master);
            else
            {
                master.mid = masterID;
                UpdateData(master);

            }
            #endregion
            #region detail part save
            if (MasterIDForUpdation == 0)
                mID = GetMaxMeetinNumber_ID("2");
            else
                mID = masterID;

            for (int i = 1; i <= RowNumber; i++)
            {
                MeetingSchedulDetail detail = new MeetingSchedulDetail();
                //TableRow row = tbladdnewmeeting.Rows[i-1];
                detail.name = name[i];
                detail.cnic = nic[i];
                detail.designation = designation[i];
                detail.company = company[i];
                detail.address = address[i];
                detail.mid = mID;
                saveDataDetail(detail);


            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) { }

  }
```

> error
>   http://localhost:57927/forms/AddNewMeeting.aspx/SaveMeetingShechudar
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: `Internal server error` means something is not right on the server side code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the [WebMethod] attribute.Which is in the System.Web.Services namespace:

```
**[WebMethod]**
public static void SaveMeetingShechudar(string MDate, string MTime, int MPurpose, int masterID, int RowNumber, string[] name, string[] nic, string[] designation, string[] company, string[] address)
{
    int mID = 0;
     try
        {

        #region master part save
        MeetingSchedulMaster master = new MeetingSchedulMaster();
        master.m_date = Convert.ToDateTime(MDate);
        master.m_datetime = MTime;
        master.m_host = UserID;
        master.m_puposeid = Convert.ToInt32(MPurpose);
        master.m_entry_date = DateTime.Now;

        if (masterID == 0)
            saveDataMaster(master);
        else
        {
            master.mid = masterID;
            UpdateData(master);

        }
        #endregion
        #region detail part save
        if (MasterIDForUpdation == 0)
            mID = GetMaxMeetinNumber_ID("2");
        else
            mID = masterID;

        for (int i = 1; i <= RowNumber; i++)
        {
            MeetingSchedulDetail detail = new MeetingSchedulDetail();
            //TableRow row = tbladdnewmeeting.Rows[i-1];
            detail.name = name[i];
            detail.cnic = nic[i];
            detail.designation = designation[i];
            detail.company = company[i];
            detail.address = address[i];
            detail.mid = mID;
            saveDataDetail(detail);


        }

    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
```

}